# Insert into textbox c# mdb database

Tags: c#, database, insert

Having Trouble with the insert code in the database, trying to insert all of the code into the corresponding textboxes and it is not working.

I am getting NO errors, but the sql code is not working.

```
  public partial class CreateAdmin : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public CreateAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            db.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb";
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            db.Open();
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("insert into Customers(CustID,CustPassword,CustFirstName,CustLastName,CustAddress,CustEmail)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", db);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", iDTextt.Text);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPassword", passText.Text);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustFirstName", fnText.Text);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustLastName", lnText.Text);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", AddText.Text);
            db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustEmail", EmText.Text);
            db.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: does this even compile ? You are adding parameters to your connection. doing execute query on the connection and so forth. you don't need an adapter you need an oledbcommand with this code.

Comment: The `OleDb` stuff doesn't support **named parameters** (like `@CustID`) - you need to use `?` as placeholders in your SQL, and the parameters are **positional**

Comment: I answered my own question, thank you for pointing it out to me @Philli

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class CreateAdmin : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public CreateAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            db.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb";
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            db.Open();
         OleDbCommand   df = new OleDbCommand("insert into Customers(CustID,CustPassword,CustFirstName,CustLastName,CustAddress,CustEmail)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", db);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", iDTextt.Text);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPassword", passText.Text);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustFirstName", fnText.Text);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustLastName", lnText.Text);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", AddText.Text);
            df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustEmail", EmText.Text);
            df.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.Close();
        }
```